# Arrival meeting place at Frankfurt Airport

Tags: luggage-storage, train-stations, fra

A friend is arriving in Frankfurt from Canada (premium economy), 10 minutes before I arrive from Australia (business class)   We will take the train to Lake Konstanz from the station in the airport.  Where should we meet up?   Would the business class lounge be convenient?   I will also be leaving some luggage at the airport for two weeks.
My thanks,
Glinda

Comment: Where to meet and what's convenient are a matter of opinion. You mention storing luggage -- if you're also asking about that, that needs to be a separate (and explicit) question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a marked "meeting point" (Treffpunkt, I think) in the lower (Arrivals) level of Terminal 1, Concourse B. That's the central area of the airport terminals, and would be a reasonable place to meet even if your flights arrive at different concourses.